# Watson IoT - Unable to send device commands to ESP8266 using NodeRed

Tags: publish, iot, ibm-watson, node-red

I am working on IoT using IBM Watson. I am able to successfully send the built-in action for Reboot/Reset, from the console to esp8266. However, when I try to send the reboot command from NodeRed application to esp8266, it does not work. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my NodeRed application snapshot [Node Red Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foxNY.png)

Also below is the configuration of each node

[IBM Watson IoT configuration Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1J9K.png)

[IBM Watson Inject Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddVlg.png)

My device code is exactly the same as [esp8266 as managed device](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/run-an-esp8266arduino-as-a-iot-foundation-managed-device/) except the few config parameters like Device Id and Device Type and Wifi credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Your red triangle on your IOT node suggests a configuration error, which means that the node is not able to connect to the IOT server. Check the node configuration - the pencil for the api key and scroll down for rest of the panel you show - to remove the red triangle.

Once you have got rid of the red triangle and you are still not seeing any commands sent, and you have followed the set-up instructions then it may be that you are missing the security settings step. On the Watson IOT platform select `security > policies > connection security` Then set the appropriate option.